# Enabling CORS for google cloud function hosted on google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Using Google cloud function i have hosted a static website ,I made a cloud function too but I need to invoke it using xmlhttp using javascript

This is what I have followed:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

`gsutil cors get  gs://<My Bucket Name>`

**I updated the origin url to * .**

Gives me the response I needed:

```
[
  {
   "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
   "method": ["GET"],
   "origin": ["*"],
   "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]
  }
]
```

Even tried with this config:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["*"]
    }
]
```

Here is what i found on the network tab which looks perfect .

[image]

I tried to even clear the cache but it gives me the same CORS error .

[image]

Comment: I see that you are accessing to the fuction not ht ebucket, I think that the problem might be that the CORS is not enabled on the Cloud Function, you enabled it only on the GCS bucket. Please take a look at [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests)

Comment: The solution is to add/set the appropriate HTTP response headers returned by your Cloud Function to allow a request from the other domain. This security protection is implemented by your browser. Before executing the XMLHttpRequest an HTTP OPTIONS request is sent to Cloud Functions to verify that your domain can make this request. This is failing either due to missing HTTP response headers or incorrectly configured HTTP response headers. The Google article in @Edgardo comment is good. Do not set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` except for testing. Specify your domain.

Comment: Good article to help understand CORS: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b

Comment: @JohnHanley exactly done , now it's working but I have used this middleware https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cors/ ,the google docs with recommends to add header was not working as expected.